# no viable overloaded '=' and inheritance

Tags: c++, eclipse, inheritance, reference

I have the following class structure but when I build, I keep getting the error:

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
                        p1 = new HumanPlayer();
                        ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../Test.cpp:14:7: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'HumanPlayer *' to 'const Player' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
class Player {
      ^
1 error generated.
```

```cpp
class Player {
public:
    void getMove(int player) {
        cout << "Get move" << endl;
    }
};

class HumanPlayer: public Player {
public:
    void getMove(int player) {
        cout << "Get Human move \n";
    }
};

class MyClass {
public:
    int mode;
    Player p1;

    MyClass() {
        mode = 0;
        cout << "Choose a mode: \n";
        cin >> mode;
        switch (mode) {
            case 1:
            p1 = new HumanPlayer();
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        p1.getMove(0);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the `Player p1;` to `Player* p1;` and changed `p1.getMove` to `p1->getMove` but then it did not work correctly. It printed `Get move` instead of `Get Human move`.

Comment: `new` returns a pointer. In the second case, getMove is not marked `virtual` so it is not polymorphic.

Comment: A constructor should do simple and basic initialization of the object. It should not do advanced things like terminal input and output. Better leave that to other functions.

Comment: I suspect that you have been programming in some other languages, where `new` is the way you create objects. C++ is not those languages. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about polymorphism.

Comment: Yes I've been using Java and quite new to C++ (hence the use of `new`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as commented above

```
p1 = new HumanPlayer();
```

is valid if p1 is declared as pointer, unlike java you can in c++ assign with and without the new keyword...

in your case declaring p1 as pointer will be ok

```
Player* p1{nullptr};
```

and later

```
p1 = new HumanPlayer();
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to make the parent method `virtual void getMove(int player)=0;` to make it work.